# ASP.NET MVC - Authenticate once and only once until session out

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, request

**Setup**

I am using custom Forms Authentication - all standard stuff.

In the Login action on my Account controller,

- I check the user's details against the db
- If successful I create a Forms Authentication ticket
- Store the logged in members db row id in UserData in the ticket
- Encrypt the ticket
- Store the ticket in a cookie
- Add the cookies to the Reponse.Cookies collection
- Redirect to Index Action on Home Controller

I registered a handler in global asax for the AuthenticateRequest event. In my handler,

- I retrieve the cookie from HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
- If the cookie exists I decrypt the value of the Forms Authentication ticket in the cookie
- Retrieve the user's details from the db using the Id stored in the authentication ticket UserData.
- Create a custom principal and set the user (it has a custom LoggedInUser property) to the user I retrieved from the db.
- Set the HttpContext.Current.User to the custom principal

**Problem**

I debug a request for the home page after I have logged in and note that the AuthenticateRequest handler in global.asax is hit more than once per page request. I've checked the HttpContext.Current.Request.Path and this is because each resource on my page (effectively, every HTTP GET) is firing the authenticate requet, so, GET jquery.js, GET logo.png etc...

**Question**

On the first handled AuthenticateRequest I go to the db and then set the HttpContext.Current.User to my custom principal. What would be a good way to avoid going to the db for subsequent HTTP GETs that cause the AuthenticatRequest to fire. Effectively, authenticate once and once only until the user closes their browser or until the Authentication Ticket expires.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `AuthenticateRequest` method in your Global.asax I would recommend you writing a global action filter. This way the action filter will apply only before executing some action and populate the User. In fact a custom `[Authorize]` attribute is the best way to achieve that:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!authorized)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // TODO: go ahead and work with the UserData from the authentication cookie
        // basically all the steps you described for your AuthenticateRequest handler
        // except for checking the presence of the forms authentication cookie because
        // we know that at this stage it exists and the user was successfully authorized

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution, so long as the user does not need to provide authorization to individual resources (such as photos, or pdf's or other files the user may want to control access to).

Comment: Those resources should normally be served through a controller action and thus fallback to the standard ASP.NET MVC authorization process.

Comment: Not necessarily, one might use a web.config location, for instance.  However, since authentication is being done at the action level, then there won't be any authorization at the global level.  Which may be fine.  I just want to point out that this approach is only valid if you're only securing controller actions.

Comment: Personally I never use the `<location>` element in my ASP.NET MBVC applications to perform authentication and authorizatin.

Comment: This is an interesting way to perform Authentication and Authorization. I've never considered this but am researching now. I would have automatically gone down the Global.Authenticate_Request route. I have come across this article (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx) which I am finding to be quite useful. Darin, I will update my solution with your suggestion and test and then post further comments. thanks for your suggestion... always good to learn something new.

Comment: accepting this answer and raising another question. This seems like the right way to go...